# Como fazer autenticação com Devise via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails, devise

Preciso fazer *login*, por exemplo, na home do meu site usando a GEM Devise com AJAX. Alguém sabe alguma forma?

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria uma requisição para a página que gera o formulário de login por ajax.

Depois, basta enviar uma segunda requisição com os dados informados pelo usuário, sem esquecer os tokens para evitar CSRF (e quaisquer outros dados necessários).

A resposta da requisição deve retornar os cookies de autenticação que deverão ser utilizados nas próximas requisições.

Comment: Concordo com Bruno, porém você vai precisar fazer um override do Devise Registratition [link sobre](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)